# postgresql left outer join (with jsonb column) won't use my index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, outer-join

The following query isn't using the indexes that I expect and I don't understand why:

```
SELECT client_order.id                as "client_order...id",
       client_order.account_id        as "client_order...account_id",
       client_order.exchange_id       as "client_order...exchange_id",
       client_order.order_id          as "client_order...order_id",
       client_order.cancel_requested  as "client_order...cancel_requested",
       client_order.algo_def_id       as "client_order...algo_def_id",
       client_order.data              as "client_order...data",
       exchange_trade.id              as "exchange_trade...id",
       exchange_trade.account_id      as "exchange_trade...account_id",
       exchange_trade.exchange_id     as "exchange_trade...exchange_id",
       exchange_trade.data            as "exchange_trade...data",
       exchange_trade.edits           as "exchange_trade...edits",
       exchange_order.id              as "exchange_order...id",
       exchange_order.account_id      as "exchange_order...account_id",
       exchange_order.exchange_id     as "exchange_order...exchange_id",
       exchange_order.client_order_id as "exchange_order...client_order_id",
       exchange_order.data            as "exchange_order...data",
       exchange_order.edits           as "exchange_order...edits"
from client_order
         LEFT OUTER JOIN exchange_trade
                         on exchange_trade.account_id = client_order.account_id
                             and exchange_trade.exchange_id = client_order.exchange_id
                             and exchange_trade.data ->> 'order' = client_order.order_id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN exchange_order
                         on exchange_order.account_id = client_order.account_id
                             and exchange_order.exchange_id = client_order.exchange_id
                             and exchange_order.data ->> 'id' = client_order.order_id
where client_order.account_id = 'foo'
  and client_order.algo_def_id = 1
```

The explain plan (https://gist.github.com/npomfret/822eb439fbf4e5a23b990ce727de405d) looks like:

[image]

```
Hash Right Join  (cost=11114.43..20169.94 rows=1552 width=2884) (actual time=291.188..646.682 rows=2228 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (((exchange_trade.account_id)::text = (client_order.account_id)::text) AND ((exchange_trade.exchange_id)::text = (client_order.exchange_id)::text) AND ((exchange_trade.data ->> 'order'::text) = (client_order.order_id)::text))
  Buffers: shared hit=8025 read=7708
  ->  Seq Scan on exchange_trade  (cost=0.00..8328.48 rows=58038 width=835) (actual time=4.415..323.106 rows=58114 loops=1)
        Filter: ((account_id)::text = 'iYdkCl49kMSWNzOsEx6Z4uydaZ53'::text)
        Buffers: shared hit=4 read=7599
  ->  Hash  (cost=11087.27..11087.27 rows=1552 width=2049) (actual time=284.136..284.137 rows=1574 loops=1)
        Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2762kB
        Buffers: shared hit=8021 read=109
        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=2748.06..11087.27 rows=1552 width=2049) (actual time=89.153..159.859 rows=1574 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (((exchange_order.account_id)::text = (client_order.account_id)::text) AND ((exchange_order.exchange_id)::text = (client_order.exchange_id)::text) AND ((exchange_order.data ->> 'id'::text) = (client_order.order_id)::text))
              Buffers: shared hit=8021 read=109
              ->  Seq Scan on exchange_order  (cost=0.00..7869.49 rows=37479 width=1080) (actual time=0.813..33.820 rows=37479 loops=1)
                    Filter: ((account_id)::text = 'iYdkCl49kMSWNzOsEx6Z4uydaZ53'::text)
                    Buffers: shared hit=7305 read=96
              ->  Hash  (cost=2720.90..2720.90 rows=1552 width=969) (actual time=82.364..82.364 rows=1574 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1554kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=712 read=13
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on client_order  (cost=64.19..2720.90 rows=1552 width=969) (actual time=9.386..12.576 rows=1574 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: ((algo_def_id = 82) AND ((account_id)::text = 'iYdkCl49kMSWNzOsEx6Z4uydaZ53'::text))
                          Heap Blocks: exact=712
                          Buffers: shared hit=712 read=13
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_client_order_2  (cost=0.00..63.80 rows=1552 width=0) (actual time=8.552..8.552 rows=1574 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: ((algo_def_id = 82) AND ((account_id)::text = 'iYdkCl49kMSWNzOsEx6Z4uydaZ53'::text))
                                Buffers: shared read=13
Planning time: 43.301 ms
Execution time: 660.347 ms
```

I have indexes on both exchange_trade, and exchange_order that I would expect to get used:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_exchange_trade_2 ON exchange_trade (account_id, exchange_id, (data->>'order'));
```

And

```
CREATE INDEX idx_exchange_order_2 ON exchange_order (account_id, exchange_id, (data->>'id'));
```

I don't understand what going wrong here and I think the query could go much faster if the indexes were being used.  Any advice greatly appreciated.

... [edit] after @jjanes suggestion I turned off seq scan (using `set enable_seqscan=off`) and got the following explain plan (after running the query twice)

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=65.02..22733.70 rows=1552 width=2884) (actual time=0.544..32.358 rows=2228 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=16680
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=64.61..12723.30 rows=1552 width=1804) (actual time=0.525..16.230 rows=2228 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=7555
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on client_order  (cost=64.19..2720.90 rows=1552 width=969) (actual time=0.496..2.046 rows=1574 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: ((algo_def_id = 82) AND ((account_id)::text = 'iYdkCl49kMSWNzOsEx6Z4uydaZ53'::text))
              Heap Blocks: exact=712
              Buffers: shared hit=725
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_client_order_2  (cost=0.00..63.80 rows=1552 width=0) (actual time=0.397..0.398 rows=1574 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((algo_def_id = 82) AND ((account_id)::text = 'iYdkCl49kMSWNzOsEx6Z4uydaZ53'::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=13
        ->  Index Scan using idx_exchange_trade_2 on exchange_trade  (cost=0.41..6.43 rows=1 width=835) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=1 loops=1574)
              Index Cond: (((account_id)::text = (client_order.account_id)::text) AND ((account_id)::text = 'iYdkCl49kMSWNzOsEx6Z4uydaZ53'::text) AND ((exchange_id)::text = (client_order.exchange_id)::text) AND ((data ->> 'order'::text) = (client_order.order_id)::text))
              Buffers: shared hit=6830
  ->  Index Scan using idx_exchange_order_2 on exchange_order  (cost=0.41..6.44 rows=1 width=1080) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=2228)
        Index Cond: (((account_id)::text = (client_order.account_id)::text) AND ((account_id)::text = 'iYdkCl49kMSWNzOsEx6Z4uydaZ53'::text) AND ((exchange_id)::text = (client_order.exchange_id)::text) AND ((data ->> 'id'::text) = (client_order.order_id)::text))
        Buffers: shared hit=9125
Planning time: 0.713 ms
Execution time: 32.538 ms
```

So now it uses the two indexes as expected.

Comment: I don't think the image is unreadable.  Just click on it.  Anyway, have added something that I hope is better.  Will update again shortly.

Comment: I see three indexes beeing used. Which is not bad for three tables being joined. Also: 2.5 ms is still too slow?

Comment: Edited again but using 'real' parameters, the result is quite different.

Comment: PostgreSQL thinks using those indexes would be slower, since you would be hitting so much of the table anyway.  Maybe it is right.  For testing, you could just `set enable_seqscan=off` before running the query to see what actually happens, but make sure to neutralize for caching effects.

Comment: Thank you @jjanes - turning that off was quite interesting.  On the 1st run, the query returned in a similar time (was slightly quicker).  The explain plan showed that it was using the indexes that I hoped it would use.  The second time I ran the explain plan it went down from ~500ms to ~30ms. ... so what's going on?

Comment: Please post an answer as an answer, you can accept your own answer after the minimal wait. Then it's clear that you found a solution & that your question is not still open.